# Strange behaviour in Mac OS terminal

Tags: zsh, macos

My mac terminal was working fine until recently, but right now it is showing a lot of strange characteristics:

- My original Machine name is not appearing, else the machine's name is appearing as `x86_64-apple-darwin13`
- The terminal is taking a lot of time to start up. And during the startup, apart from `-zsh`, things like `Rcmd` and `javareconf` and `xcodebuild` also show up on the top
- No matter what the CWD, the folder icon always appears with a question mark.

Why is this happening, and what can be done to make it go back to normal?

Comment: Is the App store currently updating XCode (could explain the processes)? Are you on a public or other-than-usual Wifi network (might change the computer's name)? Is a system update in progress?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. Basically my terminal was automatically starting in a `conda` environment, and in the `z_profile` the hostnames from the `conda` environment and the default hostname were clashing.